# Time Machine : Can't find deleted files in Time machine

Tags: time-machine

I just took Backup of my mac via Time Machine, the problem is :

- I can't see my file in Time Machine which i deleted it from mac.
- Is it true that if i delete some files from mac they will be deleted from Time Machine also (on next back up)?

Secondly, Does Time Machine takes complete Back up every-time or it just add updated or newly added files to old backup?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Can you see the files if you just browse the backup volume directly in `/Volumes/`?

If a file is deleted, it won't be included in new snapshots, but there will probably still be older snapshots that have it.

The folders for backups only contain files that have changed. Other files and folders are just [hard links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link). If a file has been modified after the last snapshot, the whole file is copied instead of storing a delta. See the [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_Machine_%28Mac_OS%29) for more information.

Answer (score -2):

I only can say that Time Machine is not working correctly. 
It is just a diskspace hog. 
TimeMachine does not back up every file (90% of the time when I need some files few days ago, I can't find that file in time machine.)
And how TimeMachine decides to backup a file or not to backup a file is unknown mystery.

Comment: Can you back up these statements with evidence? I'm using TM for a few years now and never had any issues with getting files back.

Comment: They have fixed that bug. You had used TM for years but did you test it out on that period? OCT 2012.